# Replace in all in all folder

Tags: replace

I have the same problem that here :

[replacing a complex pattern using sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41981202/replacing-a-complex-pattern-using-sed/41991966)

I have tried the solution but :

- the file is not saved
- It's only for one file (**I want to apply to all files in all folders**)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly :

http://www.garzul.tonsite.biz/wordpress/2016/07/20/how-to-remove-malicious-code-infecting-every-php-files-of-a-website/

Thanks to author.